# How to connect to AWS Elastic Search with from Browser with AWS Client VPN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-vpc, aws-elasticsearch, aws-vpn

I have a AWS VPC with 3 private (A, B, C) and 1 public subnet. I have created a Client VPN which has association with A and B. Authorization Rules are for anyone. The route tables are the default route tables of A and B (which is the main route table). I have created a private server in A which has a private 10.x.x.x ip address and I am able to connect to it locally using my client VPN. Which implies that my client VPN is configured properly. It also has split tunnel and public DNS enabled (173.0.0.2 and 8.8.8.8).

Now I created an elastic search domain in A. I got the ES and Kibana endpoints, and they look like this :

```
https://vpc-search-me-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com
```

But when I open it in browser it does not work. I know its inside VPC but at the same time, I am using Client VPN. I saw the documentation, which tells it should be possible with the VPN. Anyone successfully configured it ?
When I create it outside VPC I can properly access it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was a security group issue. The security group which I used, was only open for port 22. I made it open for all port, then it worked. I think I need to open only the elastic search port and then it should work as well.